# Making a MS Word document "absolutely" read only

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is it possible in vba to make a document read only and in such a way as to prevent any user from making any changes to it?

The protect method for the document object allows you to make a document read only, but as soon as the user tries to edit the document it provides access to the Restrict Editing Pane which gives the user access a "Stop Protection" button.

I would like to prevent the Restrict Editing Pane from appearing.

Comment: Save the doc as a PDF?

Comment: Sadly not an option for various reasons. Would be much easier if I were able to do so, but the read only document has to be presented in Word

Comment: I know of no way to repress the task pane. You can, however, set a password so the user can't remove the restriction. You might also look into IRM (Information Rights Management) that's been around for quite some time. FWIW Word was designed as and IS an EDITOR, not a viewer. IRM is the closest you're going to get, with Read-only permissions the next possible level.

Comment: You can apply 'filling in forms' protection to the entire document, with a password. That way, even if the user accesses the Restrict Editing Pane (which doesn't automatically show the way it does with 'read only' protection), they'll still need to know the password before they can do anything. Do be aware, though, that this can be circumvented by inserting the content of the protected document into another document via Insert|Object>Text from file.

Comment: Thanks I have no issue with copying and pasting into another document. Just need to prevent editing in my ole container if don't have edit rights (doc is saved to database). What I may do is fire off a timer every few seconds to check if the document has been changed and, if so, revert to the original and advise them they cannot make changes. Alternatively, I could try and detect whether the mouse is over the "Stop Protection" button and catch any attempt to click on it. I already have mouse hooks in the app so it probably wouldn't be too difficult to add something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it doesn't seem possible to stop the "Restrict Editing" panel from opening. It is possible to prevent the user from enable editing by adding a mouse hook and catching any mouse clicks within the Restrict Editing panel. Code in Delphi is

```
Hdl := WindowFromPoint (Mouse.CursorPos);
GetClassName (Hdl, clsName, 256);
GetWindowText (Hdl, wText, 256);
if (uppercase(clsName) = 'BOSA_SDM_MSWORD') 
and (uppercase(wText)= 'PROTECT DOCUMENT') then {do whatever}
```

This catches any clicking within Restrict Editing panel and is not pinpointedto the "Stop Protection" button. I would assume it would be possible to drill down further to identify the button specifically, but it seems to me unnecessary to do so. Also, if the class name or window text changes then the function will fail.

Aside from being clunky and potentially not future proof, it does however work.